# is there a better way to append the parameters in to list for Python?

Tags: python, list, append

Write a function called append_three_elements. This function takes four arguments as parameters. First is a list that we will be appending to, and the next three and values to be added to the list. This function should return a new list with the three values appended in order at the end.

For example,
append_three_elements([], 1, 2, 3)

you would expect to return
[1, 2, 3]

```
def append_three_elements(lst, a, b, c):
    lst1 = lst.copy()

    lst1.append(a)
    lst1.append(b)
    lst1.append(c)

    return lst1
```

Comment: can you share a better code/fuction to run this problem?

Comment: In python you can just `return lst + [a, b, c]`, but you should double check the instructions — the list comes first in the arguments: `append_three_elements([], 1, 2, 3)`

Comment: Thanks Mark! I forgot about that

Comment: @KateKiatsiri another way, just for fun is `return [*lst, a, b, c]`

Comment: Ah! Thanks! @juanpa.arrivillaga :)

Answer (score 3):

It's a recursive function without an end. It will keep going round and around without ever stopping.
Try this instead:

```py
def append_three_elements(a, b, c, lst):
    new_lst = lst.copy()
    for i in (a, b, c):
        new_lst.append(i)
    return new_lst
```

This takes a copy of the list (if you just use `new_lst = lst`, it will still refer to the same object), then appends each of the three different values before returning a new list (it doesn't modify the original).

Comment: Mark Meyer does have a very concise way of doing the same thing, by the way. Preferentially use his if you're willing to part with your format.

Comment: Thanks! I like both! :)

Answer (score 3):

A fun & short solution. Mark's solution, however, is more specialized and is likely the right answer you are looking for.

```py
def append_three_elements(lst, *args):
    return lst + list(args)

lst = append_three_elements(['lol'], 1, 2, 3) 
print(lst) # >>> ['lol', 1, 2, 3]
```